# Include appengine-api-1.0-sdk.jar when deploying in GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jar, memcached, appcfg

**UPDATE**

Following the advice I was given, I decided to deploy a smaller project with just a class calling this line:

```
 _cache = MemcacheServiceFactory.getMemcacheService();
```

Now I'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/appengine/api/memcache/MemcacheServiceFactory
```

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071310/appengine-classnotfoundexception-com-google-appengine-api-datastore-datastorese) that this is because I'm missing the `appengine-api-1.0-sdk.jar` but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334746/error-while-deploying-a-project-to-google-app-engine/7342227#7342227) it says there is no need to include it.

My problem now is that **if I try to include it in the deploy, by adding it to the WEB-INF\lib directory, it gets ignored.** If I try with a different jar (non related to GAE) it gets deployed just fine.

For instance, both of this versions had the `appengine-api-1.0-sdk.jar` in \lib, but version 5 also had a different jar (`bcprov-jdk15on-147.jar`). The size difference between those two is because of that.
[image]

**To sum up, my question is, should I deploy the `appengine-api-1.0-sdk.jar`?
 And if so, then how can I avoid it getting ignored?**

[Link to .rar with project.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4p45mjTMTnLbzE4aUczeTM0TEU/view?usp=sharing)

Project Dependencies, they are the default ones for a web application that is going to be deployed to GAE from NetBeans

[image]

---

I´m trying to implement Memcache so that I can use the one provided by GAE when I deploy the app.

Once it´s deployed when I try to run it I get an `IllegalStateException`:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Committed
```

This happens on this line:

```
private MemcacheService _cache=MemcacheServiceFactory.getMemcacheService();
```

What could I do to fix it?

Comment: Are you sure that the line of code (MemCacheService) you are thinking is the culprit? I do not see anything in the stack trace that supports your assumption. Does the application work if you comment out that line/related? The exception is from Jetty trying to tell you that response was already committed and cannot reset the Response. [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#reset--)

Comment: @SaiPullabhotla I added a `System.out.println` before and after this line of code and the one after never gets printed, but the one before does. The rest of the code uses `_cache`

Comment: Perhaps you should try this [sample code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/memcache/src/main/java/com/example/appengine/memcache/MemcacheConcurrentServlet.java) in a stand alone Servlet and see what happens.

Comment: @SaiPullabhotla thanks for the tip, I did just that I realized what the error but i haven't managed to fix that one either

Comment: What are the exact dependencies you have in your project?

Comment: @SaiPullabhotla I just added the dependencies to the question

Answer (score 1):

The stack trace suggests that you are trying to write something or set something on your HTTP response *after* you already committed it. It is not related to your use of Memcache.